# Update model from database without system tables?

Tags: entity-framework-4

Is there any option that allows to ignore sys tables when updating model from database?
In my case I always have sysdiagram entity and related objectset.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Just deselect the tables you don't want to add/update in the dialog:
[image]

Comment: It's when you are creating. I already have the model and I need option to exclude entity from the model. In my case it's sysdiagram that shows up each time I do updating from database model. I mean that each time you run "update from database model" it would grab all tables into entities. I don't need them all. I need the specific entity generation. I don't need entity generation for each table in database. Is there any way to mark them?

Comment: If you delete the `sysdiagrams` entity in the designer and then click `Update model from database` don't you get a dialog similar to the one in the picture? It should be called `Update wizard`. If you do, make sure the `sysdiagrams` table is deselected and see what happens.

Comment: That is the point, I have no such dialog. Sound like it's possible only on creating first time

Comment: That's weird. Are you using VS 2010, btw? Have you tried deleting and re-creating the model? Then you can deselect the table when creating the model.